# Xcode Lock an object when maximizing the window

Tags: xcode, resize, window

I'm looking for the following:

I have an object in the .nib file a (box). Whatever happens to the window, resizing, maximizing,... I want the box to be at the same place and have the same width and height at all costs.

How is this possible?

thx!

Answer (score 1):

Since xCode 4.3 I think, objects use auto layout. To disable this, go to the first tab in the inspector. Then uncheck "use autoLayout". Then just go to the layout tab and in the "autorizing" box chek the arrows going from left to right and up to down! Here are some images:

1.

[image]

2.

[image]